# Non-censored percentage values as Dependent Variables, which regression model?

Tags: regression, interval-censoring

Im working with percentage values for the first time and I looked at which models apply here. In the justification for e.g. logistic regression for percentage data I see the fact mentioned that percent values are censored/ only exist between 0 and 1.

Looking at my dataset I have Return on Assets (ROA) as the dependent variable which means that its possible that my values can go below 0 and above 1. Negative ROA in a company is certainly possible.

My question therefore is how this influences my choice of model? Can I use simple regression since my data is now basically normal interval values? Or might there be a more fitting regression type?

Cheers

Comment: The first thing is find the (conditional) distribution of response variable, ROA. If ROA itself or its transformation  follows normal distributed, then use linar model (include simple linear regression)

Comment: right, that i can certainly do that.

Comment: Just to clarify, (fractional) logistic regression is used for proportions in particular, not percentages in general.

Comment: Why is there a difference between percentages and proportions/ratios? isnt that mathematically the same?
I get there is a difference between censored and non censored but percentages are also ratios, so why deal with them with different models?